# Track user from web page to app install & open

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services, user-tracking, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I have a requirement where there is a promotional mobile web page where the user can click to download and install the app via AppGallery. When the user opens the app it should display custom content and record that back to our API based on the tracking ID (coming from the web page).

If the user installed the app normally (eg. didn't go through the promo page) then no custom content displayed.

How can the app know that it was installed and opened via a promo web page?

I'm using react-native.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the AppLinking hyperlink in the promotion page to implement this function.

For Detail,pls kindly refer:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-applicationscenarios-0000001054263231?ha_source=hms1

Hope this could help with your issue. :)